# Different results painted when added shadow (drawing path)

Tags: android

When I have this code to add shadow:

```
// set shadow
paint.setShadowLayer(2, 1, 1, Color.BLACK);
// Important for certain APIs
setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paint);
```

I get this:

[image]

When I have this code to add shadow:

```
// set shadow
paint.setShadowLayer(2, 1, 1, Color.BLACK);
```

I get this:

[image]

Can you see it? Its blurred on the second picture but that piechart looks as it should look. On the other hand first picture has nice shadow but is messed up. Why?

PS: If i don't set up any shadow piechart is not blurred and is not messed up. But I need to get that shadow there.

**EDIT:**

Class to draw piechart:

```
  public class MyGraphView extends View {
public static final int PADDING = 4;
private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private float[] value_degree;
int strokeWidth;
private int[] COLORS = { Color.parseColor("#47B243"),
        Color.parseColor("#DB262A") };

// size of bigger half circle
RectF rectf = new RectF(2, 2, 62, 62);
// size of smaller half circle
RectF rectf2 = new RectF(9, 9, 55, 55);
// size of the smallest half circle
RectF rectf3 = new RectF(16, 16, 48, 48);

int temp = 0;

public MyGraphView(Context context, float[] values, int size) {

    super(context);
    // setting up size of pie chart dynamically
    int difference = size / 9;

    rectf.set(PADDING, PADDING, size + PADDING, size + PADDING);
    rectf2.set(difference + PADDING, difference + PADDING, size
            - difference + PADDING, size - difference + PADDING);
    rectf3.set(difference * 2 + PADDING, difference * 2 + PADDING, size
            - difference * 2 + PADDING, size - difference * 2 + 
PADDING);
    // setting up brush size
    strokeWidth = size / 15;
    // assign degrees of agree and disagree to array
    value_degree = new float[values.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        value_degree[i] = values[i];
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    for (int i = 0; i < value_degree.length; i++) {
        // set type of "brush"
        paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        // set shadow
        paint.setShadowLayer(2, 1, 1, Color.BLACK);
        // Important for certain APIs
        // setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paint);
        // agree
        if (i == 0) {
            final Path path = new Path();
            paint.setColor(COLORS[i]);
            // draw 3 paths to show 3 curves
            path.addArc(rectf, 180, value_degree[i] - 4);
            path.addArc(rectf2, 180, value_degree[i] - 5);
            path.addArc(rectf3, 180, value_degree[i] - 6);
            // draw the path
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

            // disagree
        } else {
            temp += (int) value_degree[i - 1];
            paint.setColor(COLORS[i]);
            final Path path = new Path();
            path.addArc(rectf, temp + 180 + 4, value_degree[i] - 4);
            path.addArc(rectf2, temp + 180 + 5, value_degree[i] - 5);
            path.addArc(rectf3, temp + 180 + 6, value_degree[i] - 6);
            // draw the path
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
            
        }

    }
}
}
```

**EDIT2:**

When I edited it like this:

```
setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Red part kept running drawing in that circle trajectory.

Comment: Can you show more draw code?

Comment: @Jedil I already did, please heeelp :).

Answer (score 1):

`setShadowLayer` is not supported in hardware accelerated mode [see here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#unsupported)

So you should set view to software with `setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);` and it should work well. Maybe you got some bug in drawing?

Comment: I have it all the time as LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE and if I write null instead of paint it keeps drawing that red part around check my second edit in the question. Please keep trying, thank you.

Comment: add `setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);` just before your `drawPath(..)` methods

Comment: Not helped, the same result ;/ it looks like loading spinner. But without that line it looks ok .. why?

Comment: It's hard to say, try using different Paint objects and if this not work  maybe use one Path object and reset it (i'm guessing now).

Other thing not related to your problem is, that creating new Path in onDraw method is waste of processor/memory time.

Comment: Where should I create the Path instead? I have tried few things with paint so be patient then edit a bit your answer and i mark it as right. I just dont know how to assign 2 paints to drawPath(). Because I found out that color setted in setShadowLayer is ignored and only color of paint is counted. But I need to have path painted with color green and red but shadow to be black do you know how to use 2 paints?

Comment: Ok I have found out the answer but I will vote your answer up. Thank you for the help.

Comment: It;s strange answer. Best

Comment: I was also shocked but I saw a thread where it was exactly like this setLayerType method was called on the layer not on paint.

Comment: But you was calling `setLayerType` on your custom `MyGraphView` view

Answer (score 0):

I have found out. Method `setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);` should be called in the activity where I am assigning graph to linear layout so the result is:

```
myLinearLayout.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```